# jQuery post returns no response data

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, post

I have this code

```
$(document).delegate('#login', 'pageinit', function(event) {

console.log('inside login page')
$('#loginform').submit(function() {

    // Get the value of the username and password
    var myusername = $("#username").val();
    var mypassword = $("#password").val();

    // Post to the login route
    $.post(global_urlstub + '/customer_login', {username: myusername, password: mypassword}, function(data) {

        alert(data);
        console.log(data);
        if (data.flag == true) {
            alert('123');
            console.log(data);
            jQuery.mobile.changePage('#page1');
        }
        else {
            alert('12345');
            console.log(data);
            $('#errmsg_login').html(data.msg);
        }

    }, "json" );

    return false;

});
```

});

My server returns hash with key `flag`. However this code returns me no data to console or alert ,  while post request is successful. What am i doing wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would agree with Hemant_Negi that this is a problem with you server not returning valid JSON. The following code based on yours works fine (change of URL in there too which returns valid JSON):

```
var myusername = 'a', mypassword = 'b';
$.post('http://ip.jsontest.com', {username: myusername, password: mypassword}, function(data) {
    alert(data.ip);
    console.log(data);
    if (data.flag == true) {
        alert('123');
        console.log(data);
        jQuery.mobile.changePage('#page1');
    }
    else {
        alert('12345');
        console.log(data);
        $('#errmsg_login').html(data.msg);
    }
}, "json" ).fail( function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
    alert(textStatus);
});
```

If you change that URL, the call to fail() should alert an error message.

Comment: im using sinatra as backend, and im pretty sure i have valid json there. More then i have completely similar code on my backend for another piece of js code, and that works fine

Comment: If you use a browser like Chrome, open the developer tools (F12) and watch the Network tab as your code makes the AJAX request. If you click the request, Chrome will show a series of tabs (Headers/Preview/Response/Cookies/Timing). If you look at the contents of the response tab, it should be quite clear if you have a valid JSON response or not. Firebug has a similar Net tab if you use FF and I assume IE has some equivalent or use Fiddler.

Answer (score 4):

It happens when you server is not returning a valid JSON

try it without datatype first like below..

```
$.post(global_urlstub + '/customer_login', {username: myusername, password: mypassword}, function(data) {

            alert(data);
            console.log(data);
            if (data.flag == true) {
                alert('123');
                console.log(data);
                jQuery.mobile.changePage('#page1');
            }
            else {
                alert('12345');
                console.log(data);
                $('#errmsg_login').html(data.msg);
            }

        });
```

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that you take any debugging output code in your server side script.

Also, using Firebug or chrome tools, you can easily check out the response from the server to see if it is in valid JSON format.